# Using rails helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've found a helper method that I would like to use to resize embedded videos on my site. I've tried using this method several ways but received multiple undefined method errors. Here's the method:

```
def resize_video(new_width,new_height)
    width,height = embed_code.match(/width=.?(\d+).*height=.?(\d+)/).to_a.drop(1)
    embed_code.gsub(width,new_width).gsub(height,new_height)
end
```

I would like to apply this method to the `<%= raw link.embed_code %>` portion of my view, available [HERE](https://gist.github.com/1307472), to change the width and height to the desired values. Where should I put the method and how should it be called?

**Update**

Per Karel's advice, I put the method in links_helper.rb and used `<%= raw (link.embed_code).resize_video %>` in the view but received this error `undefined method resize_video for #<String:0x492bf40>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to put the helper method in the corresponding helper of the view(ie. if the view file belongs a controller xyz, there should be a helper with name xyz_helper). This is the rails convention. If the helper method is used in multiple controller views, we can put it in application_helper.

If you are getting undefined method for embed_code, we have to pass that variable as follows

```
<%= raw resize_video(link.embed_code, width, height) %>
def resize_video(embed_code, new_width, new_height)
  width,height = embed_code.match(/width=.?(\d+).*height=.?(\d+)/).to_a.drop(1)
  embed_code.gsub(width,new_width).gsub(height,new_height)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting this `undefined method resize_video for #<#<Class:0x4a6bfb0>:0x4a69610>` I've tried so many different ways, could this be a rails 3.1 issue?

Comment: I have not worked on rails 3.1 yet, but i don't think this could be a rails 3.1 issue. Most probably this could be because of broken code in the helper file or not probably loading the helper. If link is a model instance, then you may put the above code in a model method and call it from the view.

Comment: I winded up putting it directly in the controller, it's my first iteration and I'm not very specific about HOW it gets done. I just needed the feature. I used your modified function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Place your helper methods in a file name `video_helper.rb` in `helpers` folder. More [here](http://railspikes.com/2008/8/22/how-to-fix-your-rails-helpers).